# Where may I find the official docs for Windows 7's SUBST command?

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

Where may I find the official docs for Windows 7's SUBST command?

Comment: As in subst /?  Exactly what are you looking for?

Comment: "As in subst /?" No. As in e.g. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491006.aspx but for Windows 7. "Exactly what are you looking for?" The official docs for Windows 7's SUBST command. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one specifically states it is for Windows 7:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc726014.aspx

> Applies To: Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Server 2000, Windows Server
>   2003, Windows Server 2003 R2, Windows Server 2003 with SP1, Windows
>   Server 2003 with SP2, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2,
>   Windows Server 2012, Windows Vista, Windows XP
>
> Associates a path with a drive letter. If used without parameters,
>   subst displays the names of the virtual drives in effect.

Windows 7 shares many underpinnings with the Windows Server OSes, and so it's document was under their section.

I searched Technet for "subst windows 7" and this was the first result.

Comment: "Windows 7 shares many underpinnings with the Windows Server OSes, and so it's document was under their section." Well found. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the technet page for the command I think you're after: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491006.aspx

Running the following also gives some info:

```
subst /?
```

Comment: That technet page is for Win XP, not Win 7.